# Fill or no Fill on Playground?

Tags: fortnite-battle-royale

I was playing by myself on playground, first time I played I was fairly excited even though I was on my own. However after the first round, I noticed that The No Fill changed to Fill.

Problem is, I cant change the Fill or No Fill and The server alternates bewteen Fill or No Fill on certain periods of time. Is this a crazy bug, or is that normal?

Comment: My guess would be that it depends on server population at the time you're playing? I haven't played playground but I noticed it is automatically no fill for me and I couldn't switch it to fill manually.

Comment: But for me, after I play a No Fill, it changes to Fill. I can change it to no fill by re-clicking playground in select game mode. It pretty sure its a bug

Comment: Additionally, I have noticed Filling with other people(In V2) mainly playing on console(Nintendo switch) I havent checked recently, (Havent tried Fill in 2 days), but today on PC, fill wouldnt matter. Meaby epic dosent want us to play with other people on playground, and was a big glitch.

Comment: With the new V3, you can choose fill or no-fill

Comment: @TBNR I am aware of that, This question was posted when V1 was out, witch was the glitch. Btw, it's V4 now :/ It was updated not to long ago.

Answer (score 1):

Select playground mode then go to settings and select 'select gamemode ' and come back into battle royale, fill will be on.

Comment: This fixes it, but it doesn't answer the question: Is this a bug or not?

Answer (score 0):

**tl;dr**
This is a bug. You can't fix it as of right now, but fill/no-fill doesn't matter.

So, this is a bug that is in playground **as of right now**. It may be fixed sometime in the near future - I think it will - but you can't fix it right now. I don't see why you would care about it as it doesn't do anything, though. No matter if it's set to fill or no-fill, you will be in a game with everyone in your party and - to start - you will be on the same team.

Comment: In V2, it dosent matter. But at the time I posted when it was V1, when it was Fill, it would acually pair me up with other "random" people. I acually just noticed that today while playing on Fill on PC(Woudnt pair me up with other plp)